# How should I understand this 1.5 V to 90 V voltage step-up network?

Tags: step-up, voltage-doubler

I am learning about [Jim Williams's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Williams_(analog_designer)) avalanche pulse generator.

It is in page 93 of *[AN47 - High Speed Amplifier Techniques](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an47fa.pdf)*.

[image]

I don't understand the circuit's voltage step up network, which is 1.5 V to 90 V.

It looks like C2 and D2 form a [Villard voltage doubler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler#Villard_circuit). C2, D2, D3 and C1 look like a [Greinacher voltage doubler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler#Greinacher_circuit).

What is the purpose of D1 and C4?

How should I understand this 1.5 V to 90 V diode-capacitor voltage step-up network?

Comment: There's always a Villard doubler in a Greinacher doubler.  The Greinacher is just a Villard followed by a peak detector.

Comment: The flyback voltage after L1 is released (SW1 off) supplies C4 and C1 (through C2) both. In this interval the L1 flyback voltage + C2 voltage are added to C1. In opposite interval when L1 is charged (SW1 on) the C4 supplies C2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D1 and C4 are a normal part of the [LT1073](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1073fa.pdf) circuit:

[image]

The junction of D1 and C4 is a DC voltage that would normally be the output of the circuit.

C2, D2, D3, and C1 form a Greinacher voltage doubler that is fed by the pulses from the boost converter.

The way it is built, D1 and C4 generate a DC voltage, then C2, D2, D3, and C1 generate a higher DC voltage that is added to the voltage from D1 and C4.

You get about three times the unregulated voltage from this circuit than you would if you removed C2, D2, D3, and C1.

This is of course regulated to the required 90V with the feedback through the 10M and 24k feedback network.